# Does anyone know of a simple way to get an 8CH ADAT signal into a laptop/desktop?

Tags: audio, recording, product-rec, multi-channel

The only interfaces I can find with ADAT cost more than I am willing to spend, and have a lot of features and inputs that I do not need.

Ideally this would be a simple USB/FIREWIRE/PCI device with 1 ADAT input and output.

Support for at least WinXP would be a must.

Somthing in the $0-100 range.

Comment: Off topic, but you might want to consider the Behringer ADA8000 and connect the analogue signal to your PC. I don't know any other ADAT solutions below $100...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the cheapest FireWire/ADAT interface would be M-Audio's **[FireWire 1814](http://www.m-audio.com/products/en_us/FireWire1814.html)**, still exceeding your budget though ($300), unless you'll buy second hand.

[image]